# how to upload a file in github with size greater than 25 mb

Tags: file, github

I am new to github and I wanted to upload my ML project code and datasets to github and when I am trying it, it says that file cant be uploaded because of the reason that it is greater that 25mb
[image]

is there any way that I can upload a file in github with size >25mb

**please anyone help me to know how can I upload a file with size greater than 25mb.... on github**

Comment: Look at Git LFS.

Answer (score 1):

Only [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) would allow you to upload and reference such a file, but you need to do it from a local clone (instead of directly with the GitHub Web UI)

See for instance "[Git Large File Storage Tutorial](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Git-Large-File-Storage/)" from [Lei Mao](https://twitter.com/matchaleimao), to `git lfs install` and `git lfs track` that file.

But the best practice remains:

- either to have smaller sets, as in [selva86/datasets](https://github.com/selva86/datasets) or [jbrownlee/Datasets](https://github.com/jbrownlee/Datasets)
- or to have said dataset stored elsewhere, and referenced in [awesomedata/awesome-public-datasets](https://github.com/awesomedata/awesome-public-datasets)